# Emscripten - How to get uint8_t array from C to JavaScript?

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

I have an array type of uint8_t in C. A function called getResultArray will return this array. How can I get this array in JavaScript?

> uint8_t * getResultBuffer() { return resultBuffer }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer returned from the C function is an offset into the ArrayBuffer that Emscripten uses to represent memory. For viewing as uint8_t, access the memory using `Module.HEAPU8`.

Here is an example, using em++:

**fill_array.cpp:**

```
#include "stdint.h"

extern "C" {
    uint8_t* fill_array(int n);
}

uint8_t* fill_array(int n) {
    uint8_t* arr = new uint8_t[n];
    for(uint8_t i=0;i<n;++i)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var Module = {
          onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
            var fill_array = Module.cwrap('fill_array', 'number', [])
            var n = 16;
            var ptr_from_wasm = fill_array(n);
            var js_array = Module.HEAPU8.subarray(ptr_from_wasm, ptr_from_wasm + n);
            alert(js_array);
          },
        };
    </script>
    <script async type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Results in the following:

`0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15`

For this to work, you'll need to add the following arguments to **em++**:

`-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS='["_fill_array"]' -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS='["ccall", "cwrap"]'`

See full source code in [This repo](https://github.com/adilevin/wasm)

Comment: What if the array is in stack? Can you still use HEAP8 to access it in JS?